# Get AD groups of Every user into a CSV

Tags: powershell, active-directory

i tried to get the ADGroups of all users in the domain.
basically i want to do an

```
$users = Get-ADUser -All $true
>>
>> $report = Foreach ($user in $users) {
>>   $groups = $user | Get-ADUserMembership
>>
>>   # create output objects with username and groups:
>>   Foreach ($group in $groups) {
>>     [PSCustomObject][ordered]@{
>>       UserDisplayName   = $user.DisplayName
>>       UserPrincipalName = $user.UserPrincipalName
>>       GroupDisplayName  = $group.DisplayName
>> }}}
>>
>> # print a table with desired formatting
>> $report | ft
```

but the parameter -all doesnt exist for Get-ADUser.
does anyone had this problem and maybe found a solution?

Comment: Use an * as filter and the maximum search base (e.g. the domain) tho get all users like in [this example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/activedirectory/get-aduser?view=windowsserver2022-ps#example-1-get-all-of-the-users-in-a-container)?

Comment: $users = Get-ADUser -filter *
>>
>> $report = Foreach ($user in $users) {
>>   $groups = $user | Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership
>>
>>   # create output objects with username and groups:
>>   Foreach ($group in $groups) {
>>     [PSCustomObject][ordered]@{
>>       UserDisplayName   = $user.DisplayName
>>       UserPrincipalName = $user.UserPrincipalName
>>       GroupDisplayName  = $group.DisplayName
>> }}}
>>
>> # print a table with desired formatting
>> $report | ft

seems to work now. but i dont get the groups that users are member of listed properly. any idea what im missin

Comment: You don't get any groups? Or only groups of one user? I would make a function out of that foreach and return the cumulated list of all groups from that function.

Answer (score 0):

Did something simelar, you need to get the root Domain with get-adforest.
In our company the root Domain consists of 2 Layers, so for such an example you can use:
Get-ADUser -filter * -searchBase "DC=Layer2,DC=Layer1"

Answer (score 0):

This one did it.

```
    $users = Get-ADUser -filter *
>>
>> $report = Foreach ($user in $users) {
>>   $groups = $user | Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership
>>
>>   # create output objects with username and groups:
>>   Foreach ($group in $groups) {
>>     [PSCustomObject][ordered]@{
>>       UserDisplayName   = $user.SamAccountName
>>       UserPrincipalName = $user.UserPrincipalName
>>       GroupDisplayName  = $group.name
>> }}}
>>
>> # print a table with desired formatting
>> $report | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Encoding Default -Force  c:\temp\adusergroups.csv
```